# Why is Konsole hanging when I switch to it?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, konsole, krusader

I'm on Kubuntu 20.04 with Plasma 5.18.5 (running Kwin), Qt 5.12.8 and Kernel 5.4.0.74-generic with an AMD Ryzen 9 3900x, 64GB RAM and an AMD Radeon PRO WX 2100 on an SSD.

After some time of my machine running, some Konsole processes start to hang when I switch to them. I will see the window decoration of Konsole, but not the window content. If I wait for 10-30 seconds, it'll come back to live and working with it is snappy as usual. It does not happen with new windows, they come up instantly.

I haven't found a pattern, it sometimes happens to one I've only recently opened and only had little output in, but mostly it'll happen with processes I've been having open for quite a while and that had a few hundreds or thousands of lines of output (but then again if it was random, processes with a longer run time would have more chances to be affected).

I had the scrollback buffer set to unlimited, but have recently brought it down to 1000 lines without any luck regarding the behavior. Needless to say that it's extremely annoying.

I've also noticed that Krusader becomes very sluggish after prolonged process run time. It feels like my system is swapping heavily, but it isn't, and only some Krusader instances are affected. I don't know whether they're related, just mentioning that in case they are. Quitting and reopening Krusader reliably solves that problem.

I've switched off the compositor. I'm running Konsole maximized on a 3440x1440 display, should that matter.

Any ideas that I can try?

Comment: atop, press d for disk activity but it does not work for me  https://linux.die.net/man/1/atop  -    When "storage accounting" is active in the kernel, " another is lsof | grep krusader for open files   - the watch command on a process or its open files might help . happy hunting sherlock